# CountA: Giving wrong output in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am writing a VBA code in which I am trying to find if my range has empty values. The code I am writing is giving me True value even in case of empty ranges. I am adding the screen shots of data and code

```
    Range("A1").Select
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim LastCol As Integer

    total_rows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    net_rows = total_rows - 1
    
    LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "Starting Year"
    
    For each_row = 1 To net_rows Step 1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(each_row + 1, 2), Cells(each_row + 1, LastCol)).Select) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "True"
        Else
            MsgBox "False"
        End If
    Next
         
End Sub
```

[image: Data]

In above case it should True in two cases and False in rest of cases. But it is giving False in all cases. Range is is between column B and H. If could tell my error, it would be highly helpful

Comment: Drop the `.Select` after the range in CountA()

Comment: Remove the `Select` from `If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(each_row + 1, 2), Cells(each_row + 1, LastCol)).Select) = 0 Then`. You don't need to hold a person's hand in order to talk to him, and you don't need to *Select* a range in order to read (or set) its value.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the .Select after the range in CountA() by @Tim Williams and @Variatus

Answer (score 0):

### CountA vs CountBlank

**Tips**

- Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) about how to avoid using `Select`.
- Use `Option Explicit`, it will force you to declare all variables.
- Use objects like I did use a range object (`rng`) to make the code more readable (understandable).
- Think about this `CountA`/`CountBlank` 'business' for a while. You might not need it in this code, but it might become handy in the future.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Range("A1").Select
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim total_rows As Long
    Dim net_rows As Long
    Dim each_row As Long
    
    total_rows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    net_rows = total_rows - 1
    
    LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    
    Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Starting Year"
    
    For each_row = 1 To net_rows Step 1
        Set rng = Range(Cells(each_row + 1, 2), Cells(each_row + 1, LastCol))
        ' The problem with CountA is that it will find cells containing
        ' values evaluating to "".
        'If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
        ' Therefore it is better to use CountBlank.
        If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rng) = rng.Columns.Count Then
            MsgBox "True"
        Else
            MsgBox "False"
        End If
    Next
         
End Sub
```